# Applications of etale fundamental groups

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Etale cohomology groups plays a pivotal role in the proof of weil conjectures.

Are there any similar applications of etale fundamental groups in number theory? What was the original motivation for the development of etale fundamental groups?

Comment: you can google anabelian geometry.

Comment: To go along with what Qing said: [Deligne's paper](http://www.math.ias.edu/files/deligne/GaloisGroups.pdf) on the fundamental group of $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb Q} - \{0,1,\infty\}$ is described as life-changing by a lot of people.

Comment: Moreover, étale cohomology is a good place to find Galois representations. To some people that's what number theory is.

Comment: This is one of those questions where the canonical answer is so overwhelmingly large, that it's really hard to figure out how to give a short answer. For a very concrete application of the fundamental group in number theory you can see the classic solution to the inverse Galois problem for many simple groups using fundamental group techniques (see Serre's notes on the inverse Galois problem). As an original motivation, I would say that just like the fundamental group in topology is more geometrically simple than cohomology, the same is true in the etale world. I think one is more likely

Comment: to write down the etale fundamental group than write down etale cohomology.

Comment: You already mentioned the original motivation, which was to prove the Weil conjectures. It was known beforehand that constructing a cohomology theory satisfying certain properties would be sufficient, so that's what Grothendieck and his circle set about to do. Thinking by analogy with algebraic topology, the first cohomology objects should be essentially understood by $\pi_1$, in other words an algebraic theory of covering spaces; the finite étale morphisms were the right notion since they are the algebraic analogue of local diffeomorphisms & are locally trivial for the étale topology.